# React Native Image how to access local Image resources on the Android platform?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Everyone a great friend, good evening, today to learn the React Native encountered a very headache problem, as follows, in the version of the IOS, local images can be placed in the Xcode pictures to (for example, I placed a start. The PNG file) related directory, by using the < Image source = {{urine: 'start'}} / > can access, in the IOS mobile page view, but in the Android platform, and how to use?How do you access the local image resources?please help for me.

Answer (score 1):

use  react-native-camera-roll-picker library
**Basic Usage**

```
<CameraRollPicker
  callback={this.getSelectedImages} />
```

https://github.com/jeanpan/react-native-camera-roll-picker

Answer (score 0):

you can put all your images in

```
android > app > src > main > res >  drawabele-xxxx
```

now you can directly access your image in the app

Comment: Thanks,As you can see, I according to your method, operate, but didn't  to achieve results.
This is what you see here:
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KntxL.png